# JFS support missing on EC2 instance?

Tags: kernel, amazon-ec2, xfs, jfs

I just launched new EC2 instances with the Ubuntu precise and saucy AMIs. I installed `jfsutils`, but I am unable to mount a JFS volume:

```
$ sudo mount -a
mount: unknown filesystem type 'jfs'
```

Looking at `/proc/filesystems` it seems that neither JFS nor XFS are listed (nor BtrFS, for that matter).  There doesn't seem to be any module to load:

```
$ sudo modprobe jfs
FATAL: Module jfs not found.
```

It looks like the standard 'generic' kernel is installed:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-0-0-209 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What am I missing?  Am I just stuck with ext3/4 on this machine?

JFS did work on the 10.04 EC2 AMIs.

Comment: What kernel do you have installed? Please provide the output of `uname -a` in your question. I suspect the EC2 instance runs a specific kernel which is a minimal build, without generic modules included.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be modules were missed install them with xfsprogs

```
sudo aptitude install xfsprogs
```

Comment: I get: `E: Unable to locate package partman-jfs`.  I get the same trying to install the jfs-modules dependency directly.  I'm using the default `sources.list` with main and universe enabled.

Comment: The [partman-jfs package description](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/partman-jfs) says "Warning: This package is intended for the use in building debian-installer images only. Do not install it on a normal Ubuntu system."

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Now are you able to mount it manually ? like with ` mount -t xfs /dev/sdaXX /path/to/mountpoint`@AryehLeibTaurog

Comment: @AryehLeibTaurog Next try to install xfsprogs

Comment: Now I can format and mount XFS volumes.  But JFS still does not work.